# Why is $T_{\mu\nu}$ the Standard Notation for the Stress-Energy-Momentum Tensor

Tags: physics, terminology, notation, mathematical-physics

My question is simple: why do we use $T_{\mu\nu}$ to denote the stress energy momentum tensor, and when was the concept of the stress energy tensor first (or roughly the first) introduced (and by whom)?

Note: I'm well aware that such trivial notation differences make no difference to the actual underlying concepts. Rather I'm just wondering why the specific use of $T$? For instance, is it the case that the letter $T$ is the initial letter (in some other language) of the words *stress*
or *energy* or *momentum* (for example, I know that we use $\Bbb{Z}$ for integers because it stems from the German word *Zahl* for *number*)? I'm just curious because if it were me back in the day, I might have used the notation $P_{\mu\nu}$, because lower case $p$ is already standard notation for momentum in classical mechanics, so if I were to create a tensor for stress-energy-**momentum**, I might consider $P_{\mu\nu}$ as a reasonable notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is a $T$ensor. People do not deliberate much on choosing letters, as one can see from [Gauss's $E,F,G$](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14551/55), among other examples. $T$ happened to be the first tensor that came up in Sommerfeld's [On the Theory of Relativity I: Four-dimensional Vector Algebra, p. 767ff](https://zenodo.org/record/1424173#.YsWcG99Onv8), after he dealt with $4$- and $6$-vectors and then scalar and vector products. It was the turn of $T$ensor product. Minkowski and Abraham before that used different letters. Von Laue after followed Sommerfeld in his 1911 textbook on relativity (the very first one), and so it stuck, see [History of Topics in Special Relativity/Stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/History_of_Topics_in_Special_Relativity/Stress-energy_tensor_(electromagnetic)#cite_note-8).

Btw, $T_{\mu\nu}$ is typically just "stress-energy tensor", despite the momentum components in it. The [stress–energy–momentum pseudotensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy%E2%80%93momentum_pseudotensor) is a modification by Landau and Lifshitz, typically denoted $t^{\mu\nu}_{LL}$.

Comment: I guess I'm just a little surprised that even something such as $S_{\mu\nu}$ (stress) or $E_{\mu\nu}$ (energy) was not adopted. But oh well, history is full of curiosities :)